# Ruby randomly shuffle an array so that no element keeps its original place

Tags: ruby, algorithm, shuffle

I have an array that stores some names. Each person solves a task and then I want to assign each solution to a different person for verification. In short this means that I need to perform a shuffle in an array in a way that no element keeps its original place. The solution I thought of is to perform a shuffle in the array until the second condition is met and here is the code for it:

```
copied = names.dup
loop do
  copied.shuffle!
  valid = true
  (0...copied.size).each do |i|
     if copied[i] == names[i]
       valid = false
       break
     end
  end
  break  if valid
end

puts copied
```

Still I feel there may be a more optimal solution to this problem. Anyone has a better idea?

Comment: downvoter could you please propose a way that I can improve my question

Comment: don't worry.. chill... +1

Comment: @ArupRakshit haha I don't worry but still I would like to know why somebody thought it is not a good question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like what you're trying to do is to create a map of `{verifier => task_solver}` where `verifier != task_solver`. A simple way to achieve this is simply have each person's verify the next person's task:

```
verifiers = {}
task_solvers.each_with_index do |task_solver, index|
  verifiers[task_solver] = task_solvers[(index + 1) % task_solvers.size]
end
```

If you want a little bit more randomisation, you could use this, which uses the same algorithm but just shuffles your list before anything happens:

```
verifiers = {}
shuffled_task_solvers = task_solvers.shuffle
shuffled_task_solvers.each_with_index do |task_solver, index|
  verifiers[task_solver] = shuffled_task_solvers[(index + 1) % shuffled_task_solvers.size]
end
```

Comment: +1 Great idea. I thought of assigning the next person to each one, but I needed a random assignment. The second part of your answer solves this issue.

Comment: `verifiers = shuffled_task_solver.zip(shuffled_task_solver.rotate).to_h`

Answer (score 2):

What you are after might be called a derangement. Take a look here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations/Derangements (There is an example in Ruby).

Comment: Their example generates all possible arrangements for size n.  Still very interesting though so +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need just one shuffle. After that if some element in the copied array is in its original place you can swap it with one of its neighbours (it is clear that new places of the two elements cannot be the same as original places).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with.  I don't know if it's any better though :P

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

def jumble (array)
  new  = array.shuffle
  array.each_with_index do |item, index|
    if new[index] == item
      new[index], new[index - 1] = new[index - 1], new[index]
    end
  end
  new
end

new = jumble (list)
puts new.inspect
```

Output:

```
[4, 1, 8, 3, 7, 2, 6, 5]
```